# Auto taskkill command for Node.js build system works on sublime text 2 but not sublime text 3

Tags: windows, node.js, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I used node build system with auto taskkill cmd on ST2 without a problem, but the same sublime-build file on ST3 keeps throwing me errors as below:

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['taskkill /f /im node.exe >nul 2>nul & node', 'C:\\Users\\benkwok\\Documents\\Node_js_learning_2015\\index.js']]
[dir: C:\Users\benkwok\Documents\Node_js_learning_2015]
[path: ***some files paths ommitted***;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\benkwok\AppData\Roaming\npm;]
```

The node build system file is as below:

```
{
    "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
     "selector": "source.js",
     "shell": true,
    "encoding": "utf-8",

    "windows":
    {
        "cmd": ["taskkill /f /im node.exe >nul 2>nul & node", "$file"],
    }
}
```

The "cmd" under "windows" is the auto taskkill.  It works perfectly on ST2 that every time I hit f7 or ctrl+b to run the js file it kills the previous one first.

I googled for a resolution and tried to replace the cmd to the following, it works on ST3.  However it means I need to manually kill the previous process every time before running a new one.

```
"windows":
    {
        "cmd": ["node", "$file"],
    }
```

Does anyone has a better suggestion on how to pull the same autokill cmd off on ST3?

Answer (score 2):

Use the setting below:

```
{
    "cmd": ["taskkill","/f","/IM","node.exe","&","node", "$file"],
}
```

In Sublime Text, "cmd" is an array that coniains the command to run and its desired arguments. If you want to run several arguments/commands, just combine these arguments/commands with a comma, and ST3 will automatically add a space between each arguments.

So the settings above will be parsed such as the following:

```
taskkill /f /IM node.exe & node $file
```

Comment: Explain what this does and why